# Including seasonal dummies in regression

Tags: regression, categorical-data, seasonality

I've downloaded some data. Problem is some of them have been seasonally adjusted while the rest have not. I could not find data that have all been seasonally adjusted.

Wonder if I run a regression on this mix of variables with a set of quarter dummies, will there be any impact on my regression results?